# Make Bootstrap Carousel Fluid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the jQuery Carousel function in Bootstrap. I'm using a fluid layout, and I was wondering if it was possible to make these images and stuff stretch with the page also?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the jquery Carousel is but if you want image to stretch as the page does, you just need to define the image width as a percent (ie 100% or 50%). it will resize as the page does. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap's [sample carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/) is already fluid (they place the carousel div outside the "container" div). However, the images inside the carousel are still not fluid, even if you apply `class="img-responsive"` to the images. To make the carousel images fluid also, add this to your custom CSS file:

```
.carousel .img-responsive {
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it should work by putting your carousel in a fluid row..

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        *etc*
    </div>
</div>
```